# Query running total from week to week and use it to calculate row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I have a table that stores Inventory Data by InventoryID and week. I need to somehow query and keep a running total of the DeltaQty from the prior weeks in order to figure out what is the Cumulative AvailQty for each week (Running total + AvailableQty)

```
CREATE TABLE InventoryWeekly (
    StartDate date NULL,
    EndDate date NULL,
    InventoryID varchar(11) NULL,
    AvailableQty float NULL,
    OutgoingQty float NULL,
    DeltaQty int NULL,
    CumulativeAvailQty int NULL
);

INSERT INTO InventoryWeekly (InventoryID, StartDate, EndDate, OutgoingQty, AvailableQty, DeltaQty, CumulativeAvailQty)
VALUES
('00069','2023-01-09','2023-01-15', 1, 2, 1, 0),
('00069','2023-01-16','2023-01-22', 2, 2, 0, 0),
('00069','2023-01-23','2023-01-29', 3, 0, -3, 0),
('00071','2023-01-09','2023-01-15', 5, 8, 3, 0),
('00071','2023-01-16','2023-01-22', 2, 3, 1, 0),
('00071','2023-01-23','2023-01-29', 3, 1, -2, 0);
```

I've created this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/leWmUr8A).

I've tried using `LAG` function but it isn't cumulative.

Comment: can you add your expected output for given sample data?

Comment: Why are you using a `float` for some quantities and an `int` for others? A `float` is likely poor choice for the data type here, as it's unlikely a base 2 value will be an appropriate value for how much you have of something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with

```
ALTER TABLE InventoryWeekly ADD CONSTRAINT InventoryWeekly_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StartDate)
```

It would help if you could describe what the output looks like.

A *running total* is just the sum of all previous values, which you can obtain as

```
SELECT iw.StartDate, iw.EndDate, iw.InventoryID, iw.AvailableQty, iw.OutgoingQty, iw.DeltaQty,
    SUM(h.AvailableQty) AS TotalPreviousAvailableQuantity
FROM InventoryWeekly iw
    LEFT JOIN InventoryWeekly h ON iw.StartDate > h.StartDate
GROUP BY iw.StartDate, iw.EndDate, iw.InventoryID, iw.AvailableQty, iw.OutgoingQty, iw.DeltaQty
```

Comment: All supported versions of SQL Server (and even some unsupported) allow for windowing of `SUM` so why not use that?  A triangular join isn't going to be efficient here; especially with larger numbers of rows.